# Time evolution of the worldlines of 2 particles

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

Suppose I have a lab frame that is freely falling in a gravitational field of the Earth -- assume non-homogeneity-- and a uniform constant electric field in the vertical direction. There are 2 test particles in the frame -- both of mass $m$, but one is of charge $e$ and the other neutral. They are initially separated by by a vertical distance $h$. I would like to model how their distance evolves. Could anyone help me?

---

Things I've thought of (but may not be entirely right): I shall assume that the interaction between the particles is negligible.

Then the geodesic equation for the neutral particle is $$u^a\nabla_a u^b=0$$ where $u^a$ is its 4-velocity.

The worldline of a charged particle is 
$$u'^a\nabla_a u'^b=\frac{e}{m}F^b{}_au'^a$$
where $F^b{}_a$ is the electromagnetic tensor.

And then...?

Comment: Cool Question, +1!  Are we dealing with a special or general relativistic situation here?  I guess I'm leaning in the GR direction, since you mention non-homogeneity of the earth's gravitational field, indicating your concern with gravitational effects, indicating might be coming from the GR camp.  Yadda yadda yadda, 'nuff said.  SR or GR, the choice is yours.  But what is the choice?  Cheers.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Indeed, it is GR! :)

Comment: What components of the EM tensor are constant?  You say there's a constant field, but I find this wording a bit ambiguous.  Additionally, the trajectory of the uncharged particle is something you should be able to find with Killing vectors.

Comment: @Dodo:  GR, eh what?  Well, you certainly have a way of making life easier!;)  OK, GR it is then.  But we're going to have to get more information about the patient before we operate, Dr!  In addition to Murphid's valid concerns, what do you mean by "non-homogeneity of the earth's field"?  Do you intend for folks to consider the facts that the earth is a lump of heterogeneous rock and other stuff of greatly varying stress-energy, or just the non-homogeneity that merely arises from a bounded, spherically symmetric object?  I mean, the Man in the Street WANTS TO KNOW!  Me too!  Let's have at it!

Comment: @Muphrid: Sorry about the ambiguity! I think all the components of $F_{ab}$ are constant -- because the electric field is constant? Would you mind telling me a bit about the Killing vectors or perhaps give me a link? :)

Comment: @RobertLewis: Haha! I mean the latter. :)

Comment: "I think all the components of $F_{ab}$ are constant" — in which coordinate system?

Comment: @celtschk: since it's just a constant (vertical) electric field, presume it is a constant in any frame??

Comment: Since it is not a scalar field, whether the components are constant or not depends on the coordinate system. Remember, we are in a curved spacetime.

Comment: @celtschk: ah, thanks. I suppose the lab frame?